# Rename the key name in json file using python

Tags: python, json

I want to update a key name in my json file, the objects in the file look like:

```
[{"marka": "تويوتا" , "tag" : "MANF"},
{"marka": "شيفروليه" , "tag" : "MANF"},
{"marka": "نيسان" , "tag" : "MANF"}]
```

I want to change the key name "marka" into "entity", so it will be something like this:

```
[{"entity": "تويوتا" , "tag" : "MANF"},
 {"entity": "شيفروليه" , "tag" : "MANF"},
 {"entity": "نيسان" , "tag" : "MANF"}]
```

This is the code I've tried but it gives an error:

```
import json
with open("haraj_marka_arabic.json", "r") as jsonFile:
     data = json.load(jsonFile)

for d in data:
    d["entity"] = d.pop("marka")

with open("haraj_marka_arabic.json", "w") as jsonFile:
    json.dump(data, jsonFile)
```

The error is:

> File "marka.py", line 8, in 
>           d["entity"] = d.pop("marka")
>       KeyError: 'marka'

Comment: I think the problem is in your input data. If you print(d) before assignment what is the last value before error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update json key name in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61209084/how-to-update-json-key-name-in-python). Your **identical** question from 2 hours ago for which you received 3 answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the input data.

just add a debugging logger into the for loop where you change the key name and print `d.keys()` before changing the key name just like this ->

```
for d in data:
    print(d.keys())
    d["entity"] = d.pop("marka")
```

to see if the key is actually `marka` and not something else.

Answer (score 0):

The code works well, the problem is in your input data. One of the jsons in your file doesn't have `marka` key.

In order to find the invalid jsons, you can run:

```
print([d for d in data if "marka" not in d])
```

Comment: I tried your code and it prints the data after editing the key name to "entity" but the data in the file is the same I mean the key name didn't change to "entity", how?

Comment: This code is just to find the jsons without `marka` key. You should run it after this line: `data = json.load(jsonFile)`. If there are jsons without the key, you have to decide -  fix them or decide how to process them.

Comment: the problem is solved, actually, the file was opened multiple time and it couldn't make the updates. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the rename conditional:

```
for d in data:
    if "marka" in d : d["entity"] = d.pop("marka")
```

or set a default value:

```
for d in data:
    d["entity"] = d.pop("marka",None)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
with open("haraj_marka_arabic.json", "r") as jsonFile:
     data = json.load(jsonFile)

for d in data:
    d['entity'] = d['marka']
    del d['marka']

with open("haraj_marka_arabic.json", "w") as jsonFile:
    json.dump(data, jsonFile)
```

this will help you to update values